# Not sure if fluid on clothes invalidates Ghusl

Tags: ghusl

so i'm a guy addicted to masturbation (extremely regretting it though). i do it once in two weeks. i know it's consequences and am ashamed of it. Anyways, after doing it, i immediately perform Ghusl, but fluids keep exiting. i cannot identify by the look of them on clothes if it is Sperm (Mani) or not so i'm not sure if my ghusl is invalidated and the salah which i performed is nullified or not? as a result, i keep doing ghusl again and again, performing the same salah again and again until the fluids stop exiting. whenever i go into sajdah, it comes out. The cause is obviously my sinful habit.

Comment: It's not good to announce your sins in public like this. You should have chosen nice words for your question. Anyways, try to quit this habit.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer to your question is that, sperm is only that which emerges from your penis during the orgasm. And it is caused by ejaculation. And the fluid/liquid which comes after sometime is not considered as sperm, rather it is called as Mazi(مذي). And after coming out of Mazi, you should only do Wuzu(وضو).**

If you can understand Urdu, then check the URL below, this is the Fatwa about your problem.

[Fatwa About Mani and Mazi](http://www.onlinefatawa.com/fatawa/view_scn/3523)